# Summing Clojure Ratios is slow

Tags: optimization, clojure

I'm summing a long list of Ratios in Clojure, something like:

```
(defn sum-ratios
  [n]
  (reduce
    (fn [total ind]
      (+
        total
        (/
          (inc (rand-int 100))
          (inc (rand-int 100)))))
    (range 0 n)))
```

The runtime for various n is:

- n = 10^4 ...... 41 ms
- n = 10^6 ...... 3.4 s
- n = 10^7 ...... 36 s

The (less precise) alternative is to sum these values as doubles:

```
(defn sum-doubles
  [n]
  (reduce
    (fn [total ind]
      (+
        total
        (double
          (/
            (inc (rand-int 100))
            (inc (rand-int 100))))))
    (range 0 n)))
```

The runtime for this version is:

- n = 10^4 ...... 8.8 ms
- n = 10^6 ...... 350 ms
- n = 10^7 ...... 3.4 s

Why is it significantly slower to sum Ratios?  I'm guessing that it has to do with finding the least common multiple of the denominators of the Ratios being summed, but does anybody know specifically which algorithm Clojure uses to sum Ratios?

Comment: Also, if you want to use doubles, do it before the division. Much cheaper to do a division with an int and a double retunbing a doubke than a division that has to calculate a ratio, then casts that to a double.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's follow what happens when you `+` two `Ratio`s, which is what happens at each step in the reduction. We start at [the two-arity version of +](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f572a60262852af68cdb561784a517143a5847cf/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L984):

`([x y] (. clojure.lang.Numbers (add x y)))`

This takes us to [`Numbers.add(Obj, Obj)`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f572a60262852af68cdb561784a517143a5847cf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Numbers.java#L128):

`return ops(x).combine(ops(y)).add((Number)x, (Number)y);`

`ops` [looks at the class of the first operand](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f572a60262852af68cdb561784a517143a5847cf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Numbers.java#L1027) and will find `RatioOps`.  This leads to the [`RatioOps.add`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f572a60262852af68cdb561784a517143a5847cf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Numbers.java#L704) function:

```
final public Number add(Number x, Number y){
    Ratio rx = toRatio(x);
    Ratio ry = toRatio(y);
    Number ret = divide(ry.numerator.multiply(rx.denominator)
            .add(rx.numerator.multiply(ry.denominator))
            , ry.denominator.multiply(rx.denominator));
    return normalizeRet(ret, x, y);
}
```

So here's your algorithm. There are **five** `BigInteger` operations here (three multiplies, one add, one divide):

`(yn*xd + xn*yd) / (xd*yd)`

You can see how [multiply](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#l1464) is implemented; it alone is not trivial, and you can examine the others for yourself.

Sure enough, the [divide function](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f572a60262852af68cdb561784a517143a5847cf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Numbers.java#L350) involves finding the `gcd` between the two numbers so it can be reduced:

```
static public Number divide(BigInteger n, BigInteger d){
    if(d.equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
        throw new ArithmeticException("Divide by zero");
    BigInteger gcd = n.gcd(d);
    if(gcd.equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
        return BigInt.ZERO;
    n = n.divide(gcd);
    d = d.divide(gcd);
    ...
}
```

The [`gcd` function](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#l2272) creates two new `MutableBigInteger` objects.

Computationally, it's expensive, as you can see from all of the above. However, don't discount the cost of extra incidental object creation (as in `gcd` above), as that is often more expensive as we involve non-cached memory access.

The `double` conversion is not free, FWIW, as [it involves a division of two newly-created `BigDecimal`s](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f572a60262852af68cdb561784a517143a5847cf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Ratio.java#L63).

You really need a profiler to see *exactly* where the cost is. But hopefully the above gives a little context.

Comment: It does.  Thanks!